# Background Sprite Image keeps being centred on screen

Tags: objective-c, background, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a scrollable background into my current GameScene. This is supposed to be done via **Gesture Recognition**, which I'm already using for Taps and moving other scene objects.

Unlike pretty much every other result returned by my Google searches, I don't want an infinitely scrolling background. It just needs to move with your finger, and stay where it's been moved.

**The Problem:**
*I can move the background SKSpriteNode in my scene, but as soon as I try to move it again it snaps to the center and your scrolling effectively becomes useless. It keeps resetting itself.*

Here's what I've got so far for moving my Sprites:

```
-(void)selectTouchedNode:(CGPoint)location
{
    SKSpriteNode *node = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([self.selectedNode isEqual:node]){
        if (![self.selectedNode isEqual:self.background]){
           self.selectedNode = NULL;
        }
    }

    if ([node isKindOfClass:[SKLabelNode class]]){
        self.selectedNode = node.parent;
    } else {
        self.selectedNode = node;
    }
    NSLog(@"Node Selected: %@ | Position: %f, %f",node.name,node.position.x,node.position.y);

}

- (void)respondToPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Get Touch Location in the View
        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        // Convert that Touch Location
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
        // Select Node at said Location.
        [self selectTouchedNode:touchLocation];


    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // Get the translation being performed on the sprite.
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        // Copy to another CGPoint
        translation = CGPointMake(translation.x, -translation.y);
        // Translate the currently selected object
        [self translateMotion:recognizer Translation:translation];
        // Reset translation to zero.
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Fetch Current Location in View
        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        // Convert to location in game.
        CGPoint correctLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];

        // If the selected node is the background node
        if ([self.selectedNode isEqual:self.background]) {
            NSLog(@"Scrolling the background: Node is: %@",self.selectedNode.name);
            // Set up a scroll duration
            float scrollDuration = 0.2;
            // Get the new position based on what is allowed by the function
            CGPoint newPos = [self backgroundPanPos:correctLocation];

            NSLog(@"New Position: %f, %f",newPos.x,newPos.y);

            // Remove all Actions from the background
            [_selectedNode removeAllActions];
            // Move the background to the new position with defined duration.
            SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveTo:newPos duration:scrollDuration];
            // SetTimingMode for a smoother transition
            [moveTo setTimingMode:SKActionTimingEaseOut];
            // Run the action
            [_selectedNode runAction:moveTo];
        } else {
            // Otherwise, just put the damn node where the touch occured.
            self.selectedNode.position = correctLocation;
        }

        }
}

// NEW PLAN: Kill myself
- (void)translateMotion:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer Translation:(CGPoint)translation {

    // Fetch Location being touched
    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    // Convert to place in View
    CGPoint location = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
    // Set node to that location
    self.selectedNode.position = location;
}

- (CGPoint)backgroundPanPos:(CGPoint)newPos {
    // Create a new point based on the touched location
    CGPoint correctedPos = newPos;

    return correctedPos;
}
```

**What do I know so far?**

I've tried printing the positions before the scrolling, when it ends, and when it gets initiated again.

Results are that the background *does* move positions, and once you try to move it again it starts at those new Coordinates, the screen has just **repositioned** itself over the centre of the sprite.

**Supporting Illustration:**

[image: MSPaint Diagram]

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

Comment: @dragoneye It's based off of this. . . But it doesn't work like I want it to. Its a much bigger image and isn't supposed to be constrained. I can revisit it though . . .

Comment: how many images your scrolling background contain

Comment: @dragoneye One Image only

Comment: Have you implemented any code to center any node to self.view ?

Comment: @sangony No, that's what is weird. This is the only associated code. It's position is set to centre when the scene is initialised, down in a separate init statement, but that's it, and it's been moved from there. Like I said, I print the position when I start dragging, and it's always where I moved it. But for some reason it's centred onscreen. It may have something to do with anchor point I don't know. I wish someone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the situation you are describing, but I believe that it might be related to the anchor point of your background sprite node.

in your method:

```
- (void)translateMotion:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer Translation:(CGPoint)translation
```

you have the line:

```
self.selectedNode.position = location;
```

Since your background sprite's anchor point is set to its center by default, any time you move a new touch, it will snap the background sprite's center to the location of your finger.

In other words, `background.sprite.position` sets the coordinates for the background sprite's ***anchor point*** (which by default is the center of the sprite), and in this case any time you set a new position, it is moving the center to that position.

The solution in this case would be to shift the anchor point of the background sprite to be directly under the touch each time, so you are changing the position of the background relative to the point of the background the touch started on.

It's a little hard to explain, so here's some sample code to show you:

1) Create a new project in Xcode using the Sprite Kit Game template

2) Replace the contents of GameScene.m with the following:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *sprite;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

    self.sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:self.sprite];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint nodelocation = [touch locationInNode:self.sprite];
    //[self adjustAnchorPointForSprite:self.sprite toLocation:nodelocation];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    self.sprite.position = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    self.sprite.position = location;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void)adjustAnchorPointForSprite:(SKSpriteNode *)sprite toLocation:(CGPoint)location {

    // Remember the sprite's current position
    CGPoint originalPosition = sprite.position;

    // Convert the coordinates of the passed-in location to be relative to the bottom left of the sprite (instead of its current anchor point)
    CGPoint adjustedNodeLocation = CGPointMake(sprite.anchorPoint.x * sprite.size.width + location.x, sprite.anchorPoint.y * sprite.size.height + location.y);

    // Move the anchor point of the sprite to match the passed-in location
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(adjustedNodeLocation.x / self.sprite.size.width, adjustedNodeLocation.y / self.sprite.size.height);

    //  Undo any change of position caused by moving the anchor point
    self.sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x - (sprite.position.x - originalPosition.x), sprite.position.y - (sprite.position.y - originalPosition.y));
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

3) Run the project in the sim or on a device and click / touch the top tip of the space ship and start dragging.

4) Notice that the spaceship snaps its center point to where your touch is.  If you drag and release it to a new location, and the touch the screen again, it snaps its center back to your finger.

5) Now uncomment the line:

```
[self adjustAnchorPointForSprite:self.sprite toLocation:nodelocation];
```

and run the project again.

6) See how you can now drag the ship where you want it, and when you touch it later, it stays in place and follows your finger from the point you touched it. This is because the anchor point is now being adjusted to the point under the touch each time a new touch begins.

Hopefully this gives you a solution you can use in your game as well.

Comment: Oooo. I actually tried setting the anchorpoint every time touched the screen, but it would fly off screen whenever I tried moving it again. This looks much more promising though! I'll try it as soon as I get back! Then report back here.

Comment: @Owatch   ahhh... maybe the problem with the earlier attempt was not remembering to also readjust the position after changing the anchor point!  It takes a little conversion to keep a sprite in the same location while changing the anchor point - hopefully the sample code and comments are reasonably clear about how that is done.

Comment: Uh oh, I'm using  UI Gesture Recognition to capture touch, is there any way to convert a touch location to local Sprite coordinates without using 'touchesbegan' method? I mean, I could put it in, but then there would be two different methods and it would be a little redundant, I also don't know if they would work well together: `UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];` is based on NSSet touches

Comment: Method is part of UI Gesture Recognizer it seems, but how to get the local coords is difficult to find.

Comment: It works!!!! I managed to work around by converting points from self.scene to the node as such: `CGPoint localPos = [self.scene convertPoint:location toNode:self.background];`

It flickers when you move it though, maybe there's a way to tweak that I don't know. Thanks though!